# show_most_informative_features() errors with exception in python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, typeerror, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

Issues:

```
 "line 188, in most_informative_features self._most_informative_features = sorted( TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'" while using naiveBayes classifier
```

Code:

```
print('accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testdata))
classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)
```

accuracy prints, but show_most_informative_features error out with the above exception indicating an error with naivebayes.py. Any idea on the fix?
this is the line at which exception occurs: Since, it's not a good idea to change code in standard python library, am I missing out something while invoking the function?

```
self._most_informative_features = sorted(
                features, key=lambda feature_: (minprob[feature_]/maxprob[feature_], feature_[0],
                                                feature_[1] in [None, False, True], str(feature_[1]).lower())
            )
        return self._most_informative_features[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `training_set` in `classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)` should be a dictionary where the keys are all tuples (not a mix of tuples and strings).